Pain, Suffering and Kartavya
I understand that all pain and suffering in a person's or a living being's life is the result of past karma. (correct me if I am wrong or if my understanding is incomplete)
I have a couple of questions around this, may seem obvious and common sense but please read it carefully and answer:
Q1.When I see a person or living entity in pain, or suffering(with respect to the very first line), I should assume it's due to their own past actions, now

Should I as a person develop sympathy(which is a natural tendency) and try to help them?
Should I just leave them to suffer so they are free from their bad karma?

Q2.If indeed I am able to do something to help them with the suffering , does it mean that the suffering entitled to the person was not completely delivered and it will return in some other form(of suffering)?
Q3.Should I just let everyone be and ignore all that is wrong in this world with the assumption of the universal karmic cycle balancing the scales and live my own peaceful life?
Q4. Is relieving someone of their pain my kartavya? If yes, then how can I help all around me ?
Q5.If watching someone suffer and not helping them kills a part of me , is that just my small dose of suffering that I am entitled to due to my bad karma?
Thank you for your answers!

Q1.When I see a person or living entity in pain, or suffering(with respect to the very first line), I should assume it's due to their own past actions, now
Should I as a person develop sympathy(which is a natural tendency) and try to help them?
Should I just leave them to suffer so they are free from their bad karma?
ANS
You have to do your best to alleviate that person's suffering. You don't have to worry about the other person's karma. It is Isvara who will distribute the fruits of that person's karma and not any Jiva. Isvara has not given authority to any jiva to worry about the karma of another jiva.

I abide in all beings as their inner-most soul. Disregarding My
presence within them, men make a show of worshiping Me through images.
If one disregards Me present in all as their soul and Lord but
ignorantly offers worship only to images, such worship is as
ineffective as a sacrificial offering made in ashes. A man who
persecutes Me residing in others, who is proud and haughty, who looks
upon God as the other – such a person will never attain to peace of
mind. If a man disregards and persecutes fellow beings, but worships
Me in images with numerous rituals and rich offerings, I am not at all
pleased with him for proffering such worship. A man should, however,
worship Me in images, side by side with discharging his duties, which
include the love of all beings, until he actually realises My presence
in in himself and in all beings. As long as man is self-centred and
makes an absolute distinction between himself and others (without
recognising the unity of all in Me, the Inner Pervader), he will be
subject to the great fear of Death (including every form of
deprivation of self-interest). So, overcoming the separateness of a
self-centered life, one should serve all beings with gifts, honor and
love, recognizing that such service is really being rendered to Me who
reside in all beings as their innermost soul.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.29.21-27
Need to feel for the afflicted

A Brahmana might be even-sighted and calm in disposition. But if he
cannot sympathize with the afflicted, all the merits of his austerity
come to naught like water kept in a broken pot.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana  IV.14.41
Q2.If indeed I am able to do something to help them with the suffering , does it mean that the suffering entitled to the person was not completely delivered and it will return in some other form(of suffering)?
ANS
Our job is to try to alleviate the suffering of others. There is no need to worry about whether his suffering was not completely delivered. That is the responsibility of Isvara. A jiva doesn't have to worry about it.
Q3.Should I just let everyone be and ignore all that is wrong in this world with the assumption of the universal karmic cycle balancing the scales and live my own peaceful life?
ANS
No.
Q4. Is relieving someone of their pain my kartavya? If yes, then how can I help all around me ?
ANS
Yes, it is your duty to alleviate suffering of others. Do the best you can.
Q5.If watching someone suffer and not helping them kills a part of me , is that just my small dose of suffering that I am entitled to due to my bad karma?
ANS
Just help the suffering person to the best of your ability. Don't worry about things that will be taken care of by Isvara.
